# How to define a macro conditionally based on whether it is being used in text mode or math mode?

Tags: math-mode, conditionals

I'd like to be able to make a macro `\foo` whose definition would look something like

```
\newcommand{\foo}{
  \ifintextmode{abc}
  \ifinmathmode{x\cdot y\otimes z}
}
```

so that

```
\foo $\foo$
```

produces

[image]

[This TeX.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20276/27638) seems somewhat related, but I didn't quite understand the answer and it does not directly solve my issue. I'm sorry I don't have anything more to offer, in terms of making any progress myself.

Comment: Can you make a significant example for this?

Comment: The question you linked at is trying to do the opposite : detect if there is math inside the arguments of the macro. Its solution could be adapted if there was no predefined macro for this, though.

Comment: @egreg: I'm not sure what you mean - are you asking how I'm actually planning to use this? If so, the use I had in mind was making the macro `\adeles` produce `ad\'eles` in text mode and `\mathbb{A}` in math mode. I generally try to abstract such specifics away in my questions, if they don't seem like they'd be important.

Comment: Related Question: [How do I make a macro require math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81725/how-do-i-make-a-macro-require-math-mode).

Comment: @ZevChonoles That's what I feared. You gain nothing by having a macro that does very different things according to the context. You're bound to lose track of where you are. But of course it's only my opinion. After 25+ years of TeX. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: But wouldn't the use I proposed, at least, be a very semantic definition? In text mode, it produces the word (with the benefit that I don't have to remember what command makes the necessary accent), and in math mode, it makes the symbol that represents the word. I wouldn't really like having separate commands like `\adeletext` and `\adelesymbol`; though maybe TeX would like it, I think it would be harder for *me* to parse when reading the code directly.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Are all of your adèles called `\mathbb{A}`? Semantically, the name of a class of objects is different from the name of an object in the class. By the way, "adèle" is spelled with a grave accent: ``ad\`ele``.

Comment: @egreg: Well, it's a good thing I've been using the command `\adele` to represent the word this whole time, my mistake will be easy to clean up! :)

Comment: @egreg: Well, I defer to your opinion. Do you consider it acceptable to use a macro to avoid typing accents, in general? It seems like a good idea to me, especially given the mistake you've pointed out to me. Would `\newcommand{\ringofadeles}[1][]{\mathbb{A}_{#1}}` and `\newcommand{\adeles}{ad\\`eles}` be okay?

Comment: @ZevChonoles This is more consistent, in my opinion.

Comment: Related: [\newcommand: How to determine if in math mode (and then include $ $)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46492)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{%
  \ifmmode
   x\cdot y\otimes z%
  \else
  abc%
   \fi
}
```

I should say though it's generally a bad idea to do this (or use the similar `\ensuremath` command) as TeX has a built in distinction between text and math and really the author needs to know at all times whether the document is in text or math mode, and use suitable commands in each case.

Consider the accent commands; `\hat` could have been defined as above to work in text or math mode, but instead plain TeX (and LaTeX) define `\hat` for math mode and `\^` for text mode. The implementation and semantics of the two commands are very different and superficially using the same syntax for text and math would not have been helpful.

Comment: In addition, I strongly suggest to implement the macro in a single line as so: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\forcemmode}[1]{\ifmmode#1\else$#1$\fi}` to avoid any troubles with extra inserted spaces or tab.

Comment: @Welgriv I wouldn't, it makes the code very hard to maintain, and the version as I posted here will not add any spaces.